# polynomials as functions SML

Tags: sml, ml

If I consider polynomials to be represented as functions as: type P= int*(int->int) where the first int is the order of the polynomial and (int->int) is a function that takes and index and returns the coefficient.

I should write a function that given a list it gives me a polynomial of that type
for example, form([1]) gives (0,fn 0=>1))
but the problem is when writing something like

form([1,5]) gives (1,fn 0=>1|1=>5))

I am so confused about the part fn 0=>1|1=>5 since fn is not recursive. I can find the order of the poly from the length of the list, I can visit each element in that list using x::l but how can I build this function (fn 0=>1|1=>5) with each visit of an element. I don't want an explicit answer but I need help!

Comment: Think about it this way: When the caller asks for the polynomial's n-th coefficient, that corresponds to the n-th element of the list that is the argument of your function. Does this shed some light on the problem?

Comment: yes! but how can recursion build my output function? I tried something like this but I totally got stuck afterwards:
from(x::l)= (length(x::l),fn x=>x+4|-------)) how can I build the rest of my output function?

Comment: Is this an exercise, where recursion is required?

Comment: Not necessarily. It is just the way I think of the task that I should use recursion to go through each element in the list. May be my thought is incorrect. Please correct me if I think in the wrong way

Comment: Basically you're trying to produce `List.nth`, only a curried version so that the caller only needs to provide the index. You can write a recursive abstraction `f` like this: `val rec f = fn i => f (i - 1)`

Comment: so should I only consider one index when writing fn? can you give me an example of how should that work

Answer (score 0):

Using methods from the `List` structure, this can be implemented by making a curried version of the cartesian function `List.nth`:

```
fun form nil = raise Empty
  | form xs  = (List.length xs - 1, fn i => List.nth (xs, i))
```

If you want to implement a function with *nth*'s functionality yourself, it might look like this:

```
fun form xs = 
  let
    fun nth nil     _ = raise Subscript
      | nth (y::_)  0 = y
      | nth (_::yr) i = nth yr (i - 1)
  in
    (List.length xs - 1, nth xs)
  end
```